# Simplifying a nasty has many through triangle relationship, Normalizing data and the entity relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, relationship

I'm working on normalizing some data via UI, where the data is not big data and it needs to be done by a human so I'm doing this via CRUD + forms etc on a Rails app and Postgres.

I have the following Entities:

```
Unit has many Part
Unit has many Ability,
Ability belongs to Rule
```

However, I have discovered that Abilities also needs to belong to Part as well. So Ability is a join table with a Name attribute.

```
Unit has many Part, Part has many Ability
Unit has many Ability, 
Ability belongs to Rule(Ability is a many to many join table)
```

Now what complicates this even more is from a unit show page perspective, I only care about Unit's relationship to Unique Rules via ability or Part>Ability>Rule. An ability can either belong to Unit or Many Parts. But I need the Ability table for some background processing stuff.

The Issues I'm having here are complexity;

- I have tried to do a form object for the creation of Abilities, where you can either create a Unit Ability or Unit's Part's Abilities(the collection) but this get's weird as returning a single resource is normal but where I need to return the Parts's Ability collection or this gets really weird, dealing with what is new/form errors etc.
- Ability#name needs to be normalized as it is unique to unit but now that parts also needs Ability it's duplicated along it as the join model.
- Again Unit show page only cares about It's unique relationship to Rule even through Parts. I have tried to get the form object to work but when dealing with the collection of Abilities returning what gets created is not correct because of this mess of relationships.

Any way to make this simpler?